# Accessing Assembly Information GUID in a C# Form Application

Tags: c#, guid, assemblyinfo

I would like to use the GUID in the Assembly Information of my Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition project for use in a Mutex that is used to verify that only one instance of the application is running.  How can the GUID be accessed?  I only need to use it in the `Program.Main(...)` function.  Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what this guy did for his single instance application. Check it out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically get the GUID of an application in .net2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502303/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-guid-of-an-application-in-net2-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question was asked on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5faa901a-7e70-41f4-a096-3e6053afd5ec

Here is the code exerpt:

```
public static T GetAssemblyAttribute<T>(Assembly assembly) where T : Attribute
{
    if (assembly == null) return null;

    object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true);

    if (attributes == null) return null;
    if (attributes.Length == 0) return null;

    return (T)attributes[0];
}
```

Some of the values are also available via the `Assembly` type:

[How do I programmatically get the GUID of an application in .net2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502303/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-guid-of-an-application-in-net2-0)

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  My search skills have been trumped!  The example in the linked StackOverflow post was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the static [GetExecutingAssembly method on Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) to get the currently executing assembly.

However, unless you have a [Guid attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) associated with the assembly, you are not guaranteed to have a Guid associated with the assembly all the time.

If you do have a Guid attribute associated with the assembly, then you can take the assembly instance and call [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcustomattributes.aspx) on it and it will return the Guid attribute associated with the assembly, which you can then query for the Guid.

I would suggest, however, using the fully qualified type name of the entry point of your application as the name.  It has a better semantic meaning, and is assembly-qualified, giving it a fair amount of uniqueness.

If you have concerns about someone else using that value to prevent your application from running, using a Guid isn't that much safer, someone can always reflect your assembly and get the value of the Guid.

Comment: Thanks, casperOne, but it's mainly to prevent the user from launching more than one instance of the application.

Comment: How would I get "the fully qualified type name of the entry point of [my] application"?