# IIS Application : How to get an unique ID

Tags: c#, iis, guid

I have an application that manage IIS Application instances so I am looking for a kind of GIUD to identify each applications.  This GUID must be created when the application is deployed in IIS and must be persistent to IIS/Windows updates/restarts.

I did not need the use of Microsoft.Web.Administration: I want a simple way, for each IIS application, it returns its unique ID (by a method called within it).

Here is an example of what I'm looking for and I'd like to have an unique id returned by this.????? :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
     string myUniqueID {
         get { return this.?????; }
     }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Um.... [`Guid.NewGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yeah, so make a GUID field and assign it a value on startup. Then return it in that method.

Comment: This value must be assigned by IIS in that case, and must not be the same if a deploy the same application in another IIS instance.  So this value must be set when I create my IIS Application instance (in the IIS console) and must be saved whenever I restart IIS or the server.

Comment: We might do better if you told us what *problem* this persistent, unique identifier is meant to help you to solve.

Comment: When I deploy my MVC.NET application, I would like a unique identifier is created and does not change if I turn off the server or if I make updates to Windows or IIS. This UID, then I want it back in my global.asax to manage instances of these applications that can be deployed on IIS, these UID in a centralized Oracle database and then managed in a third party application (logging, etc.). . 

So IIS UID is automatically generated during deployment and in which case I get it and in this case I would like to know how, or in another case I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assembly GUID for this purpose: In **AssemblyInfo.cs,** you can find

```
// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("307E39B9-2C41-40CF-B29F-84C8BBCD6519")]
```

To read this value, you can use:

```
public static string AssemblyGUID
{
  get {
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var attribute = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute), true)[0];
    var GUID = attribute.Value;
    return GUID;
  }
}
```

which is taken from another SO answer (you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502303/1016343)).

---

And if it is required, Visual Studio allows you to **create a new GUID** via menu **Tools -> Create GUID** - if you need a different one.

Or in C# you simply use

```
var newGuid=(Guid.NewGuid()).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(newGuid);
```

to create a new GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar.

1. Read the web.config file for a HostId setting. Preferably split your configuration file into two, with one config file that is local to the install, and doesn't get replaced upon upgrading to a new version of the website.
2. If the HostId value doesn't exist in the web.config, call Guid.NewGuid() to generate a new value.
3. Save the new value to the web config, preferably in the local section/file.
4. Return the value.

Here is some psuedo-code:

```
    public Guid HostId
    {
        get
        {
            var result = GetSetting(ConfigFileLocalSettingList.HostId).TryToGuid();
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = Guid.NewGuid();
                SetSetting(ConfigFileLocalSettingList.HostId, result.ToString());
                Save();
            }
            return result.Value;
        }
    }
```