# How do I set the GUID of an application in C#

Tags: c#, nunit, guid

How do I get the GUID of an NUnit project?

I am referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/502308/5436341) to get the GUID of the application and it's returning NULL in my case of NUnit project. Basically custom attributes of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` doesn't has a GuidAttribute.

I want GUID because in one of my testcases, I am using [GPO Save API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gpedit/nf-gpedit-igrouppolicyobject-save) and I need to pass Guid as it's last argument.

Comment: Add a `[assembly: Guid("Your GUID here")]` attribute to your project via the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: Do I need to generate a new Guid for my project? If yes, any utility to do that?

Comment: If you want a GUID, then yes. Google "GUID generator" and you'll find some (there's one built into Visual Studio if you look through the menus).