# How can i get GUID of Windows Forms in .NET Core (not .NET Framework)

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-core, .net-6.0

I can get GUID from a "legacy" .NET framework by right click on project > properties > Application and click Assembly Information...

[.Net Framework Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdnY9.png)

but, in new Windows Forms on .NET 6 (.NET Core), I do not have this button:

[.NET Core Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8TkW.png)

I try to find GUID of my Windows Forms project.

Comment: Not sure about the newer User Interface, but you can get the GUID using code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502303/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-guid-of-an-application-in-c-sharp-with-net